# Map Reduce for analyzing time series

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce, time-series, cluster-computing

I am new to map reduce concept and wonder if the following problem can be solved using it.

We have a log of data in the form like this:

```
TransID     Date           Operation   DocumentID   User
1           01/01/2010     Open        aaa          Anne
2           01/11/2010     Close       aaa          Anne
3           01/12/2010     Open        bbb          Mary
4           01/12/2010     Close       bbb          Mary
```

We want to be able to calculate different time metrics, such as:

- How much time passes between Open and Close operations average globally? or
- How much time passes between Open and Close average per each user?

Is there a simple way to achieve this with map-reduce? We are considering MongoDB or Hadoop.

The amount of data can be large - billions of records. Thanks!

Comment: This is certainly possible, I've done it before.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is you need to "flatten" your data during the map phase and send that to the reducer for your calculation.  So your key would be DocumentID (and maybe User depending on your use case) and then the value is the time and operation (put time first if it sorts better that way).  In your reducer the rows above would only results in rows being able to loop through within a key.  Here is an example of something very similar https://allthingshadoop.com/2011/12/16/simple-hadoop-streaming-tutorial-using-joins-and-keys-with-python/